# What's the difference between “c'est pourquoi” and “parce que”?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

I hear a lot of “c'est pourquoi” lately, so I just want to know what it means. Also with “parce que”.

Comment: http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/parce%20que         _          http://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/c'est+pourquoi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- *C'est pourquoi* introduces a consequence/result/effect. Exemples:

  1. *Les personnes âgées peuvent perdre la perception de la soif, c'est pourquoi elles risquent la déshydratation*: Old people may loose the ability to feel thirsty, that's why they risk dehydration.
  2. *Il y a eu la découverte du gisement gasier North Dome  dans le golf persique, c'est pourquoi il y a ces guerres en Irak et en Syrie*:  There's this  North Dome  gas condensate field located in the Persian Gulf, that's why these wars in Irak and Syria.
- *Parce que* introduces a reason/cause. Examples:

  1. *Les personnes âgées risquent la déshydratation parce qu'elles peuvent perdre la perception de la soif*: Old people risk dehydration because they  could loose the ability to feel thirsty.
  2. *Il y a ces guerres en Irak et en Syrie parce qu'on a découvert le gisement gasier North Dome dans le golf persique*: There are these wars in Irak and Syria because we've discovered North Dome gas condensate field in the Persian Gulf.

Comment: Is "c'est pour ça q'..." an option, or have I imagined it/ misheard "c'est parce que"?

Comment: @medica That's also correct (although written `que` or `qu'` depending on what follows). `C'est pour ça que...` is somewhat equivalent to `It's for that reason that...`

Answer (score 4):

Could " c'est pourquoi " mean: that's why.
And " parce que " mean: because.

Haha if it's true, I answered my own question.

Comment: You have, indeed.

Comment: Voilà pourquoi also means "This/it is why..."

Answer (score 0):

It is why  = a declarative
It is because =  implys  a relevant  past 
If one asks
Is there a god
And another replys
It is why
U may b hearing from a reverant
If another to that same ? Replys
It is because
U may b hearing from 
One not ready to drink da cool aide

Comment: WTF! Go easy on the 'shrooms, pal!